# Obtaining a specifc field from an ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I am designing a GUI which allows users to add a new cruise to the system. Within this GUI is a form which the user must fill out in order to store the new cruise in the system or my ArrayList - `final ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();`. My GUI however, consists of a JList, which displays only the names of the Cruises.

The problem is that I am storing the new Cruise with several fields assigned to it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("\nCruise Name: ").append(NameOfCruise).append("\n");
sb.append("Start Port: ").append(startLValue).append("\n");
sb.append("End Port: ").append(endLValue).append("\n");
sb.append("Start Date: ").append(model1.getValue()).append("\n");
sb.append("End Date: ").append(model.getValue()).append("\n");
sb.append("Assigned to ship: ").append(Shipname).append("\n");
Cruise.add(sb);
```

When adding the new cruise to the system, I want the new cruise to be stored with all the details (Name of Cruise, Start Location, End Location etc).However on my JList, I just want to pick out the name of the cruise, so that the JList only displays NameofCruise.

This is how I have created the Jlist and how I am adding the new Cruise object to the JList:

```
    final ArrayList Cruise = new ArrayList();
    Cruise.add("Scottish to Greek Waters");
    Cruise.add("Greek to Scottish Waters"); 
    Cruise.add(sb);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    CruiseList = new JList(Cruise.toArray()); 
    scrollPane.setViewportView(CruiseList);
    CruiseList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    CruiseList.setSelectedIndex(-1); 
    CruiseList.setVisibleRowCount(6); 
    listPanel.add(scrollPane);
    Frame1.setVisible(true);
```

Adding `Cruise.add(sb);` and calling `System.out.println(Cruise.toString());` is printing out null.

How do I tell Java to just add the name of the cruise in the arraylist to the JList?

Comment: why you are using a string for keeping all properties of object. I suggest, create a class like CruiseData and keep all information on it. then override toString function to just show its name. it might solve your problem

Comment: You mean `System.out.println(Cruise.toString());` prints `[null]`? Then, `Cruise` does only contain one element, `null`, in which case, since you call `Cruise.add(sb);`, `sb == null`? Did you set `sb` to `null` explicitly somewhere between definition and usage? I am really confused as to what the actual problem is, because IMO the behavior you describe cannot be reconstructed by the code you present.

Comment: 'sb' is meant to obtain the objects from the swing components and essentially group them together so that I have an output on the console consists of all the details of the newly added cruise together. Therefore I am am using 'Cruise.add(sb)' in the hopes that all the form details obtained and stored in the Cruise ArrayList. I'm assuming the 'null' output is arising because the string is too long for he ArrayList to hold? seeing as I have only grouped the Strings together, not the objects so the ArrayList is treating each field (Cruise name, Start Date, etc) as a separate entity?

Comment: I somehow can't imagine "null" being printed when the String is too long. While I am still not sure what the real problem is, I suspect that you meant to call `Cruise.add(sb.toString)` instead of `Cruise.add(sb)` as the latter will add the `StringBuilder` instance. Maybe you could add the generic parameters to `Cruise` to clarify the type - both for the sake of helping SO-fellows and for the sake of clean code. Is `Cruise` supposed to be an `ArrayList<Object>` or an `ArrayList<String>` (to which you could not add `sb`)?